# Зависает асинхронный парсер на первом запросе

Tags: python, парсер, asyncio, асинхронность, aiohttp

Написал скрипт для парсинга сайта с прокси, но на первом же запросе он встаёт намертво, хотя если просто вывести переменную soup, удалив ещё 23 строчку всё работает прекрасно.
Не подскажите в чём может быть проблема?
[image: Всё что он выводит после запуска и 10 минут ожидания]

````
from asyncio import Semaphore
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio
import aiohttp
#------------------------------------

global proxyList
proxyList = []

#------------------------------------
headers = {"user-agent": UserAgent()["google_chrome"]}
#------------------------------------

async def parce3(session, semaphore: Semaphore, url):
    await semaphore.acquire()
    await asyncio.sleep(1) #Перерыв между итерациями

    #Получение страницы
    async with session.get(url=url, headers=headers) as response:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "lxml")
        quotes = soup.find("table", class_="table")[1]
        print(quotes)

    semaphore.release()


async def createTasks():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        
        #Получение страниц
        async with session.get(url="https://freeproxy.pro/http") as response:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "lxml")
            pages = int((lambda x: x[x.find('center">')+14:x.find('</div>', 10)])(str(soup.find_all("div", class_="d-flex justify-content-center")[-1])))
        
        #Сбор задач
        semaphore = Semaphore(3) #Одноврменный парсинг страниц (колл-во)
        tasks = [parce3(session, semaphore, f'https://freeproxy.pro/http?page={i}') for i in range(pages)]
        await asyncio.wait(tasks)

def main():
    asyncio.run(createTasks())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()```
````

Comment: У вас в переменной pages общее количество прокси, а не количество страниц

    pages = soup.find_all("div", class_="d-flex justify-content-center")[-1].text.split()[2]
    a = int(pages) / 20
    pages = int(a) if int(a) == a else int(a) + 1

Comment: согласен, спасибо